# Detecting cookie from webapge in Android

Tags: android, cookies, html, detect

I am trying to detect if a phone has visited a website before launching an application in android. My idea is to put a cookie on the webpage, that could be stored when they visit, or check a box, or whatever. Then, when the application starts, the app would detect the cookie. If the cookie is present, one thing would occur, if not a different action. Can any one help me out here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, that should be impossible.

Android Browser stores its cookies in its own files, which is different from your own WebView, and no other application can read it. (Think about this, if other application can read all the cookies stored by Browser, it would be a serious security issue. )